# outside f:ajax for composite component

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

Is there a way I can create a composite component that can receive an `<f:ajax>` tag from outside?

I'm creating an editableText input composite component and I want to show to end user the option to append an `<f:ajax>` tag inside the input tag of my component. Is there a way to make it using composite component? EditableValueHolder don't support `<f:ajax>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved the problem a week ago. I didn't posted the answer here cause I was full of work and I forgot it. :)

Just need use this tag:

```
<c:clientBehavior name="blur" default="true" event="blur" targets="input" />
```

accordingly with this [IBM page](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jsf2fu-0610/index.html?ca=drs-), this tag isn't documented, probably is the reason to be so difficult to find it.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: It is documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/).